# Creating a pattern map in C

Tags: c, pattern-matching

So i am trying to write a code to find a pattern in a [20][20] set of data. i want to check if the first [row1, col1] is the same with [row1, col2] , [row2, col1] and [row2, col2] and if not then it moves one column to right to check the next numbers. When it finds the pattern, then i want to print ONLY the [row1, col1]. for example there are a set of number like this:

```
1 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 4 , 6 , ...

3 , 6 , 1 , 1 , 9 , 10 , ...
```

The pattern would be like this : it only shows the top left number.

```
        1
```

My code is:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void)
{
// Decalred variables
int rowIndex = 0;
int columnIndex = 0;
int mapValue = 0;
int mapRight = 0;
int mapBottomRight = 0;
int mapBottomLeft = 0;

//Stores the  data
int patternMap[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our pattern map data

//Create search pattern
printf(" \n--- PATTERN MAP ---\n\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS -1; rowIndex++)
{
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS - 1; columnIndex++)
    { 
        mapValue = classificationMap[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        mapRight = classificationMap[rowIndex][columnIndex + 1];
        mapBottomRight = classificationMap[rowIndex + 1][columnIndex + 1];
        mapBottomLeft = classificationMap[rowIndex + 1][columnIndex];
        {
            if (mapValue == mapRight && mapValue == mapBottomRight && mapValue == mapBottomLeft);
            {
                patternMap[rowIndex][columnIndex] = mapValue;
                displayValuePatternCount[mapValue - 1] = displayValuePatternCount[mapValue - 1] + 1;
            }
            printf("%.d ", patternMap[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
        }
}

// Exit
return 0;
}
```

The problem with my code is that they all start at the position [row1, col1].
How can i solve this?

thanks

Comment: please declare all the variables and remove the syntax error from your program. variable classificationMap, displayValuePatternCount are not declared. code incorrect

Comment: this line: `if (mapValue == mapRight && mapValue == mapBottomRight && mapValue == mapBottomLeft);` shoud NOT have the trailing semicolon `;`

Comment: the value `MAX_ROWS`` is not declared anyone in the posted code/  Suggest: `#define MAX_ROWS 2` after the `#include` statements.  Similar considerations exist for the value `MAX_COLUMNS`

Comment: the array: `classificationMap[][]` does not exist anywhere in the posted code.  please correct that oversight.  Similar conditions exist for the array `displayValuePatternCount[][]`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  2) suggest not adding unwarranted braces.

Comment: the contents of `classficatioMan` and `displayValuePatternCount` are never set, but those contents are being used.   Using uninitialized variables is a very bad idea.

Comment: There seems to be significant sections of code missing from the posted code.  Please correct that problem